# Convert Latin to English encoding in C#

Tags: c#, encoding, ascii, converters, latin

I am trying to convert the character `ù` to `a` in English.

example code:

```
 Encoding latinEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
 Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
 byte[] latinBytes = ascii.GetBytes(txt);
 string asciiSring = latinEncoding.GetString(latinBytes);
```

What I get in `asciiSring` is '?' instead of 'a'.

what is the way to do it properly?

Comment: It is highly improbable that you can convert a *ù* to a *a* using codepages. The *a* is part of the ASCII character set, so it is nearly always a *a* in nearly all the codepages.

Comment: And Windows 1255 is hebrew, not latin, you know it?

Comment: You right, it doesn't work with 'Windows-1252' either.

Comment: You should post a big piece of text "as is" and "how you want it to become"... Then we can try to help you.

Comment: Uhm, why are you trying to convert "ù" to "a"? I hate that term but... XY problem?

Comment: `ù` in ASCII is character code 0x97. Character 0x97 in Windows-1252 is an EM-dash (`—`). Why would you expect `ù` to turn into `a`?

Comment: I have two languages in my windows, Hebrew and English, and if I insert the character 'ש' it's received as 'ù' and i want to convert it to 'a',

Comment: The *ש* is in a Hebrew Keyboard on the same key as the *a* (see for example http://www.ehebrew.org/articles/hebrew-keyboard.php)... It is the only connection I can see... But it isn't a problem of encoding here...

Comment: Ok, got u.. i think using a Dictionary is the best way to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: @xanatos That's a good clue. There seems to be some very odd transformations going on: ש key is struck ⇒ ¿? ⇒ character code for ש from Windows-1255 (0xE9)  ⇒ 0xE9 interpreted per Windows-1252 as character ù ⇒ ¿? ⇒ ends up in a .NET String as ù ("'\u00E9'"). (It should be ש `'\u05E9'`.) But, it is actually a different keyboard layout that is wanted with the 'ש' key being used as the 'a' key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why doesn't the user insert an 'a' when an 'a' is wanted? This doesn't seem like an issue that the vast majority of applications should be concerned with. It's commonly only between the user and the OS. See "Text Services and Input Languages".

Nonetheless, the application could dynamically set the keyboard layout by assigning [`InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.currentinputlanguage(v=vs.110).aspx) to one of [`InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.installedinputlanguages(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm not sure that's visible to the user so it would be less confusing if the application provided a control or indicator.

Comment: if you have multiple keyboard languages installed you should get the option of changing between them in the status bar of Windows, near the clock (I have ITA/ENG for example)... But you can probably hide it.